# What is the strongest form of the Axiom of Choice available in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$?

Tags: lo.logic, axiom-of-choice, reverse-math

$\mathsf{Z}_{2}$ denotes second-order arithmetic. Some forms of AC are expressible in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$; for example the $\mathsf{\Sigma}_{1}^{1}$ axiom of choice is part of the theory $\mathsf{ATR}_{0}$ (i.e. it is strictly weaker than $\mathsf{ATR}_{0}$ over $\mathsf{RCA}_{0}$).

However, the following [theorem](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82056884.pdf) of $\mathsf{ZFC}$ is not provable in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$: Given a symmetric Borel set $B\subseteq[0,1]\times[0,1]$, there exists a Borel function $f:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]$ such that the graph of $f$ is either contained in or disjoint from $B$.

Hence, roughly speaking, the strength of AC available in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$ lies somewhere between the prime ideal theorem and full AC. But **What are the weakest forms of AC which are not provable in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$? What are the strongest forms of AC which are provable in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$?**

---

**Update**
I will collect here what I find out so that answers may expand or complement it, and if no answers are provided, I will eventually post it as an answer.

On page 294 of Stephen G. Simpson's *Subsystems of Second Order Arithmetic*, 2nd. ed. (2009) there are several choice schemes in the language of $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$ expressing cases of the axiom of choice (e.g. countable choice and dependent choice). Section VII.6 (p.294-303) is devoted to results relating these choice schemes to comprehension schemes.

D. D. Dzhafarov and C. Mummert, in *Reverse mathematics and properties of finite character*, Ann. Pure Appl. Logic, 163 (2012), 1243–1251, studied combinatorial equivalents of the axiom of choice, finding several examples that are either equivalent to $\mathsf{ACA}_{0}$ or strictly stronger. See also their paper: *On the strength of the finite intersection principle*, Israel J. Math., 196 (2013), 345–361; and their book *Reverse Mathematics: Problems, Reductions and Proofs* (2022) (Section 9.10.3 (p.345) - The finite intersection principle). They miniaturize and study several principles equivalent of the axiom of choice.

[This](https://victoriagitman.github.io/talks/2017/05/09/a-model-of-second-order-arithmetic.html) shows a model of $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$ with the choice scheme in which $\mathsf{\Pi}_{2}^{1}$-dependent choice fails (it includes a link to the slides of the talk).

Christine Gaßner, in *The axiom of choice in second-order predicate logic*, Mathematical Logic Quarterly, 40(4) (1994), 533-546, directly "deals with the power of the axiom of choice (AC) within
the second-order predicate logic." In particular: "the relationship between several variants of AC and some other statements, known as equivalent to AC within the set theory of Zermelo and Fraenkel with atoms, in Henkin models of the one-sorted second-order predicate
logic with identity without operation variables".

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/526053) answer by Carl Mummert in MSE offers some information on how the well-ordering theorem and the axiom of choice relate to one another in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$.

In $\mathsf{ZFC}$ there is a plethora of equivalent formulations of the full axiom of choice or weaker versions of it. However, most of the formulations which are equivalent in $\mathsf{ZFC}$ are non-equivalent in $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$. This is because $\mathsf{ZFC}$ allows us to consider power sets, but $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$ does not. Proving equivalence over $\mathsf{ZFC}$ between certain forms of the axiom of choice involves considering a set $A$ and its power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$, or even $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$. In $\mathsf{Z}_{2}$ we could talk about the subsets of $A$, but we cannot group them into the power set $\mathcal{P}(A)$. We could do this in $\mathsf{Z}_{3}$, but then we could not talk about $\mathcal{P}(\mathcal{P}(A))$, and so on.

Comment: I edited to focus the background information on expressibility, and to make the final question meaningful even if there is no unique strongest or weakest statement. Feel free to revert or edit further if this version doesn’t reflect what you want.

Comment: @MattF. Your change does not make much sense to me. You *can* quantify over Borel sets and functions in the language of second-order arithmetic, hence the statement *is expressible* in $Z_2$, it’s just not provable there (if I am to believe the reference).

Comment: Thanks for including the reference; I changed all three “expressible” (both the one I had added and the ones there originally) to “provable”, and now it all seems to fit together.

Comment: The question is perhaps still confusing: all the choice provable in $Z_2$ is provable in ZF if I am not mistaken.